# Elasticsearch - mapping with type text and keyword tokenizer, how it is indexed?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, tokenize, keyword

i'm new to Elastisearch and a little confused of how a certain field is stored in the Lucene index, since i get the error: Document contains at least one immense term in field="originalrow.sortable" .....bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 893970"

The mapping in the index template:

```
 "analyzer" : {
    "rebuilt_hungarian" : {
      "filter" : [
        "lowercase",
        "hungarian_stop",
        "hungarian_keywords",
        "hungarian_stemmer",
        "asciifolding"
      ],
      "tokenizer" : "standard"
    },
    "lowercase_for_sort" : {
      "filter" : [
        "lowercase"
      ],
      "tokenizer" : "keyword"
    }
  }
  ..
  ..
    "dynamic_templates" : [
    {
      "sortable_text" : {
        "mapping" : {
          "analyzer" : "rebuilt_hungarian",
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "sortable" : {
              "fielddata" : true,
              "analyzer" : "lowercase_for_sort",
              "type" : "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "match_mapping_type" : "string"
      }
    }
  ],
```

and the generated mapping for the field involved in the error:

```
"originalrow" : {
  "type" : "text",
  "fields" : {
    "keyword" : {
      "type" : "keyword"
    },
    "sortable" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "analyzer" : "lowercase_for_sort",
      "fielddata" : true
    }
  },
  "analyzer" : "rebuilt_hungarian"
}
```

So as i think - i might be wrong, of course - is that originarow.sortable field is indexed as text but the whole text goes into the inverted index because of the keyword tokenizer, and that might be the cause of the error.
Another thing is that the lenght of the text is about 1800 charaters and i have no clue how the size
can exceed 32K bytes.

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your field `sortable` you are using the `lowercase_for_sort` which again uses the `keyword` tokenizer that results in single token, and in Lucene largest size of a token is 32766 as explained in [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/bytes-can-be-at-most-32766-in-length/213650) post.

And if you are using some characters which takes more than 1 bytes than you can cross this limit. From [UTF docs](https://A%20UTF%20maps%20each%20Unicode%20code%20point%20to%20a%20unique%20code%20unit%20sequence.%20A%20code%20unit%20is%20the%20minimal%20bit%20combination%20that%20can%20represent%20a%20character.%20Each%20UTF%20uses%20a%20different%20code%20unit%20size.%20For%20example,%20UTF-8%20is%20based%20on%208-bit%20code%20units.%20Therefore,%20each%20character%20can%20be%208%20bits%20(1%20byte),%2016%20bits%20(2%20bytes),%2024%20bits%20(3%20bytes),%20or%2032%20bits%20(4%20bytes).%20Likewise,%20UTF-16%20is%20based%20on%2016-bit%20code%20units.%20Therefore,%20each%20character%20can%20be%2016%20bits%20(2%20bytes)%20or%2032%20bits%20(4%20bytes).)

> A UTF maps each Unicode code point to a unique code unit sequence. A
> code unit is the minimal bit combination that can represent a
> character. Each UTF uses a different code unit size. For example,
> UTF-8 is based on 8-bit code units. Therefore, each character can be 8
> bits (1 byte), 16 bits (2 bytes), 24 bits (3 bytes), or 32 bits (4
> bytes). Likewise, UTF-16 is based on 16-bit code units. Therefore,
> each character can be 16 bits (2 bytes) or 32 bits (4 bytes).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Even counting 4 bytes / character, the whole size can't exceed 7200 bytes.

Comment: @bonyolult, are you indexing just one document? maybe its in some other document which you are missing

Comment: @bonyolult any luck?

Comment: Hi, millions of documents are indexed and some of them produce the error and those are not indexed. The size of the field is constant, ~1800 characters. It is our customer's ELK stack, i asked for sample data but haven't received yet but anyway,  in princple it is impossible to go over 32K with that field.
The other question is: how it is (with the above mapping) indexed phisically? Am i right, it's indexed as text and the whole field content goes as one string into the inverted index?

Comment: @bonyolult sorry for delay in response, you need to check the Elasticsearch logs in order to see which documents causing this issue, there it will be printed clearly with error msg, reg your second question, yes you are right, its going as text but analysis process is producing just one string

Comment: Finally i received the sample data. It's gigantic, the problem is really with the size of the data content. Now the next question is how to index a document that is 1.7M characters long:)

Comment: Hi, i tried:) 
"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: Oh, sorry, i accepted. New not only to Elasticsearch but to StackOverflow, too:) And thank you for your help!!

Comment: @bonyolult glad to help always :)